# jQuery - Inserting data attribute into variable

Tags: jquery, youtube

When you click load more I am trying to load the youtube videos using their data-youtube attribute on the li. The problem is this doesnt seem to be working and it just renders out [Object object]

Anyone know what I'm doing wrong please?

http://jsfiddle.net/qxxq9u21/

```
var youtubeID = $('.video-list li').each(function () {
    $(this).attr('data-youtube');
});


$('.load').click(function () {
    var video = '<iframe src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/' + youtubeID + '?wmode=opaque?hd=1&rel=0&autohide=1&showinfo=0" frameborder="0"></iframe>';

    $('.video-list li').find('iframe').remove();
    $('.video-list li').append(video);

    return false;
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

there are multiple problems/misunderstandings in your code:

1. your `each()` function is only executed once on pageload, plus it doesn't return anything so you get nothing in your `var youtubeID`.
2. your `append()` function is applied to all list elements, so you will get all the videos in every `<li>` (in your example that's two)

**what i changed to make it work:**
so i put the `each()` function inside your `click` event, so that it's executed on every click. inside the `each()` function i appended the video-iframe to `$(this)` which in this case is the current `<li>` element `each()` is iterating. so you got the video just once where you actually wanted it to be.
and with `$(this).data("youtube")` you can read the value of your `data-youtube` attribute of your `<li>`.

**here you got a working example:**

```
$('.load').click(function () {

    $('.video-list li').find('iframe').remove();

    $('.video-list li').each(function () {
        $(this).append('<iframe src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/' + $(this).data("youtube") + '?wmode=opaque?hd=1&rel=0&autohide=1&showinfo=0" frameborder="0"></iframe>');
    });
    return false;
});
```

and here is the working [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/northkildonan/45pb1mnv/2/)

Answer (score 1):

jQuery's each returns a jQuery object, which is why you are getting [Object object] in your url. Even if that returned an array of youtube ids, you'd still be having an issue with how you are building the iframe html.

I'd suggest changing your jQuery a bit. In your click event, loop through each list item that has a data attribute of youtube, and build and replace your iframe.

```
$('.load').on('click', function(){  
    $('.video-list > li[data-youtube]').each(function(item, index){
        var video = '<iframe src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/' + $(this).data('youtube') + '?wmode=opaque?hd=1&rel=0&autohide=1&showinfo=0" frameborder="0"></iframe>';
        $(this).find('iframe').remove();
        $(this).append(video);
    });

    return false;
});
```